# Python 3.7.4 - Cant use installed packages (macOS)

Tags: macos, bash, python, homebrew, pip

So I have python 3.7.4 installed under macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 using brew (`brew install python`) and I am having some problems with it.

First off, even though this is minor, I am wondering if this is contributing to it; When brew installs python, it says the following:

```
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin
```

However, typing `pip` doesn't do anything. I have to type `pip3` for it to work.

Running `pip3 --version` gives:

```
pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

The main issue is the fact that I can't use any of the packages I have installed. For example, I've got `youtube-dl` installed through `pip3` in the past, however once I did `brew upgrade` that upgraded python 3.7.3 to 3.7.4 and broke everything.

I can prove I have it installed by doing the following (other items cut out for simplicities sake):

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
drwxr-xr-x  19 root    admin    608 Jun 29 00:07 youtube_dl
drwxr-xr-x  10 root    admin    320 Jun 29 00:07 youtube_dl-2019.6.27.dist-info
```

However typing `youtube-dl` comes up with the infamous `-bash: youtube-dl: command not found`.

I've tried numerous times uninstalling and reinstalling python to no avail.

Here is what my PATH looks like in .bash_profile:

```
PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}:${HOME}/go/bin"
export PATH
```

Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you can install youtube-dl via Homebrew as well.

Comment: Originally I did, however I needed the python version of it because there were some pip packages that had youtube-dl as a dependency, and having both around was confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Introduction**

Please read the [Homebrew and Python](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python) documentation:

> The executables are organized as follows so that Python 2 and Python 3 can both be installed without conflict:
>
> - `python3` points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x (if installed)
> - `python2` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed)
> - `python` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed) otherwise the macOS system Python. Check out `brew info python` if you wish to
>     add Homebrew’s 3.x `python` to your PATH.
> - `pip3` points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x’s `pip` (if installed)
> - `pip` and `pip2` point to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x’s `pip` (if installed)

**Which binaries to call?**

According to the above info, if you want to use `pip` from the Homebrew Python 3 installation, call it as `pip3` – more specifically, `/usr/local/bin/pip3`.

If you have `/usr/local/bin/pip`, it will be from Homebrew Python 2 (legacy). Otherwise it'll be your system Python's `pip`.

I can only recommend to install Python 2 and 3 from Homebrew and use `python` and `python3` to refer to 2.7 and 3.x, respectively, and never use the system Python. And never use `sudo`.

**Permission**

Your Python package was installed by `root` and not by your normal username. That seems wrong. Did you ever use `sudo` to install something with `pip`? If so, please avoid this in the future and try to fix the permissions:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

**Troubleshooting steps**

Running `brew doctor` should also indicate issues with your installation.

You can also try removing the Homebrew Python installation completely, and reinstalling it.

**Path**

Don't set your path like shown in the question. `python3` and `pip3` are in `/usr/local/bin`, so as long as `/usr/local/bin` is in front of your path, you're good:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/:$PATH"
```

This *should* be the default anyway, so if anything is overriding it, please modify your shell init scripts accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much slhck for the info. Inside `/usr/local/bin` I do have `pip` which is `brew`'s. Never knew `brew doctor` was a thing, I ran it but didn't report anything bad. Also already removed and installed it fresh again. And yes, I always did `sudo -H pip3 install .....`, learned it on a video once. I was always under the impression that was normal.

Comment: (I also upvoted the answer but because of my low rep it didn't display)

Comment: Ahh, no, running `sudo` with Python is *never* a good idea these days, particularly if you have an installation running in your user environment (e.g. Homebrew or pyenv). I know there is bad information about this all over the place. That's very likely what caused these problems. In fact, you may try a `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`, and then re-install Python and Python 3 through Homebrew.